# How to make a unique input value check another variable in mongoose and javascript

Tags: javascript, mongoose

```
var itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
     type:String, 
     required: true,
     unique: true, 
     uniqueCaseInsensitive: true 
  },   //name of the item
  description: String, // what the item is
  quantity: {type: Number, min: 0, max: 400}, // the amount that is there
  storageLocation: String, //where it is stored
  location: String, // where it is if not stored
  dateTaken: [Date], //date loaned out
  whoBarrowed: String, // who has the tool
  creator: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'} //the user for the item that is in the database
});
```

So I have a unique variable and I am also using users. I want to have it check the unique under the users and not the whole database. I am using mongoose and this is part of my javascript

Comment: "and I am also using users. I want to have it check the unique under the users " - i have no idea what this means. A bit more clear statement would be easier to understand

Comment: My meaning is that I have a log in to my page that makes users for the website. Everything added to the data base is under that user and no other users posting are visible. But the unique makes it so if it is under another person's login it can't be posted